Multi-objective optimization by alternating goal
Suppose you're trying to optimize two functions $y_1(\vec{x})$ and $y_2(\vec{x})$. Of course, there is not necessarily one value of $\vec{x}$ that optimizes both functions --- and your optima will instead create a Pareto front.
One approach to finding a suitable solution is to construct a linear scaling $u(\vec{x}) = a_1 y_1 + a_2 y_2$, and then optimize $u$ using standard one-objective optimization schemes.
Another approach could be to optimize $y_1$, then optimize $y_2$, then re-optimize $y_1$, etc. Is there a name for this approach or any literature on it? What might its limitations be?
